# Get object array from axios and using return value call another axios function and append the output to first result

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async-await, axios

const request = {
headers: {
"Accept": "application",
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
method: "GET",
url: '',
} as any;

```
        const result = await axios(request);

        result.data.data.map(async (ad: any) => {
            const request2 = {
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                method: "GET",
                url: '',
            } as any;

            const result2 = await axios(request2);
            ad.preview = result2.data.data[0].body;
        })

        return result.data.data;
```

preview key is not getting appended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the return-statement runs before the async map-callbacks have finished. Since you're not actually returning anything inside your map, it does not make a lot of sense to use it though. Just use a `for..of` loop:

```
const result = await axios(request);

for (const ad of result.data.data) {
  const request2 = {...}
  const result2 = await axios(request2);
  ad.preview = result2.data.data[0].body;
}

return result.data.data;
```